# How to remove only dots after initial character without followed space character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove dots after initials (without following space) and the comma before them.

If this is the input

```
Some, A.B., Author, D., Names, M.F. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.
```

...the result should be

```
Some AB, Author D, Names MF. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.
```

I tried to get the correct regex to use it with replace:

```
string.replace(/(, [A-Z])\./g, '$1')
```

But this is not working, as expected and I do not see what is going wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't `M.F.` be `MF` in desired output?

Comment: @revo You are right. But I think as it is the last one, the 'block' is at its end. That's why I think it would be better to keep this dot. It could be recognized by the followed space, which all other initials don't have...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. You should make comma and preceding spaces optional and add a negative lookahead:

```js
var s = 'Some, A.B., Author, D., Names, M.F. Lorem ipsum. Lorem ipsum.';
console.log(s.replace(/,?( *)([A-Z])\.(?!\s)/g, '$1$2'));
```